# Handle "error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT." exceptions to print them in Xcode playground

Tags: swift, xcode, exception

How do you handle generic exceptions like the kind in the title in a Swift playground? I would like to set a callback to print the exception out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
  print(exception)
}
```